# How to solve this stochastic differential equation? (Ito's formula)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm a beginner in stochastic processes and I want to solve the following stochastic equation:

$$X_t = 1 + \int_0^t X_s \sigma_s\, dB_s,$$

where $B_s$ is a standard Brownian motion. I want to apply Ito's formula and it gives me:

$$d X_t = X_t \sigma_s\, dB_t.$$

Is it a proper way to start solving it? How should I continue the calculation to solve this equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here, I think the easiest way is to look at $\ln X_t$.  Ito's formula gives \begin{align*}d\ln X_t &= \frac 1{X_t} dX_t - \frac 1{2X_t^2} dX_t dX_t \\
&= \sigma_t dB_t - \frac 12 \sigma_t^2 dt\end{align*} so we can just integrate to obtain $\ln X_t - \ln X_0 = \int_0^t \sigma_s dB_s - \frac 12 \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds$.  Since $X_0 = 1$, by exponentiating we obtain $X_t = \exp(\int_0^t \sigma_s dB_s - \frac 12 \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds)$.